# How to read sitemap.xml in cypress if there are large number of urls

Tags: cypress, sitemap.xml

I want read sitemap.xml file and then want to check status of every url present in sitemap.
URL present in sitemap are around 20K so I dont want to visit url but just wants to check status and as url count is too large wants to run every url as one test case so that one of test case failure would not affect remaining ones.

Wants to implement above in Cypress

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer here [Cypress.io - sitemap.xml validation test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61499577/16997707) that may start you off.

Instead of `cy.visit(url)` use `cy.request(url)`, it should be much faster.

```js
it('check each url in the sitemap.xml', () => {

  const results = []

  cy.request('sitemap.xml')
    .then(response => {
      // convert sitemap xml body to an array of urls
      urls = Cypress.$(response.body)
        .find('loc')
        .toArray()
        .map(el => el.innerText)
      return urls
    })
    .then(urls => {
      urls.forEach(url => {
        cy.request({
          url, 
          failOnStatusCode: false      // get status good and bad
        })
        .then(response => {
          results.push({url, statusCode: response.statusCode})
        })
      })
    })

    // use results inside .then()
    cy.then(() => {
      console.log(results)
    })
})
```

BTW putting each URL in a separate test is a big headache.

The above pattern will give you status codes on good and bad URLS, and will be faster than separate tests.

Comment: Tried this way also but with this if any url in sitemap gives timeout exception test is getting failed.

Comment: That's bad luck, it worked perfectly for me. If you add sample of sitemap perhaps I can help you out.

Comment: Do you have 20k urls in sitemap.xml.. I meant will above code work for 20k urls

Comment: You'll have to separate your tests into several chunks and not have all 20k under one block.